# Cytoscope calculate node position

Tags: javascript, cytoscape.js

I am using cytoscope.js to plot a state-transition diagram. I retrieve the nodes and edges from an API, so the number of nodes and edges are not fixed.

For testing, if I mention the position of all the nodes, the graph is rendered properly:

```
var cy = window.cy = cytoscape({
    container: document.getElementById('cy'),
    boxSelectionEnabled: false,
    autounselectify: true,

    layout: {
        name: 'preset'
    },
    elements: [{
        "data": {
            "id": "n61",
        },
        "position": {
            "x": 350,
            "y": 315
        },
    }, {
        "data": {
            "id": "n62",
        },
        "position": {
            "x": 450,
            "y": 315
        },
    }, {
        "data": {
            "id": "n63",
        },
        "position": {
            "x": 550,
            "y": 315
        }
    }, {
        "data": {
            "id": "n64",
        },
        "position": {
            "x": 50,
            "y": 405
        }
    }, {
        "data": {
            "source": "n63",
            "target": "n61"
        }
    }, {
        "data": {
            "source": "n61",
            "target": "n62"
        }
    }, {
        "data": {
            "source": "n61",
            "target": "n64"
        }
    }, {
        "data": {
            "source": "n64",
            "target": "n62"
        }
    }]
});
```

But incase of variable nodes, how can I determine/calculate the position for each node so that, they are rendered inside my viewport?

Answer (score 0):

You must have well defined source and target nodes for each edge.  An edge can not exist if source or target do not exist.

To automatically position the nodes, use a layout: http://js.cytoscape.org/#layouts